# Как вывести все расчеты с цифрами на консоль(язык R)

Tags: r

Что делает код(все операции сложения, вычитания, умножения и пр.) Чтобы перенести алгоритм на другой язык.
Есть ли такой способ?
Функции `summary`, `dput` и `дебагинг` уже пробовал. В них выводится конечные значения, а мне нужно, как эти значения получаются.

Comment: Вы хотите выяснить алгоритмы по которым работают функции, которые вы используете в скрипте?

Comment: Проанализировать исходный код используемых функций: `print(fun)`.

Comment: Да именно алгоритм. Хочу реализовать на другом языке, так как связка через скрипт медленно работает, при тестировании и оптимизации в тестере.